# Get a property from a JSON which is stored in a clob column

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a *clob* column in my table, in which I store **JSON** string. the data in the column is something like below:

```json
{
  "date": "2021/11/11",
  "name": "test",
  "errorCode": "00000",
  "type": "test"
}
```

I want to write a select query to get the name.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on 12c or higher, you can extract the value using `json_value`:

```
select json_value ( 
         '{"date":"2021/11/11", "name":"test","errorCode":"00000","type":"test"}',
         '$.name'
       ) nm
from   dual;

NM     
test
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `JSON_TABLE` provided your DB version is `12c+(12.1.0.2)` such as

```sql
SELECT jt.*
  FROM t,
       JSON_TABLE(jscol,
                  '$'                  
                  COLUMNS(
                           name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.name',
                          "date" VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.date' 
                          )
                  ) jt
```

this way, you can pick all the columns listed after `COLUMNS` keyword

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77d6a756c9fbe29678e3ff9d927b81ee)</kbd>